# AWS EC2 instance - why can't i get the admin password with the .pem file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I copied an AWS (amazon web services) EC2 instance from region x to region y by creating an image and restoring it.

Now I can't log into region y, because I can no longer generate the password using the .pem file (and have since deleted the instance from region x, but still have the file).

Why is this? Is there any way I can get the admin password so I can remote desktop to it?

Answer (score 1):

When an Amazon EC2 instance is launched from an AWS-supplied AMI, a random Administrator password is generated. This password is then encrypted using the Keypair nominated when the instance was launched. The password can then be obtained by decrypting the password using the private half of the Keypair.

It appears that you have created an AMI from the instance, copied the AMI to another region, then launched a new instance from the AMI.

This should have **retained** the same password on the new instance because, after generating the random password, EC2Config would have been configured to keep the same password.

If you no longer have a record of the password, it should still be possible to decrypt the password using the **Get Windows Password** command and the original `.pem` file. The command will display the name of the `.pem` file that you should use.

If all this fails, you can still retrieve the password by following the procedures on [Resetting an Administrator Password that's Lost or Expired](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2-windows-passwords.html#ResettingAdminPassword), which is basically:

- **Stop** the instance
- **Detach** the boot volume
- **Attach** the boot volume to another Amazon EC2 instance
- Modify a setting on the volume
- **Detach** the volume, **reattach** to the original instance
- Use **Get Windows Password**

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response, that sounds like a very complicated process to go through. I guess if passwords are involved that's probably a good thing! Cheers for the help